# Can't change default download path in Selenide

Tags: java, selenide

I tried using Configuration.DownloadsFolder but it's not present in the Configuration class. I am not able to change the default download directory. I am fairly new to this can anyone help.

Comment: It's caps sensitave, try downloadsFolder with a small d at the start instead `Configuration.downloadsFolder = yourPath;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @sorifiend i tried that it didnt work is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean "It didn't work", did you get an error? Did it not change the directory? Please show us the exact code you are trying to use to set the configuration and then to start the download. Is the code all within the same method, or do you set the config somewhere different than where you start the download?